# Github Wiki: <img> tag not working with realtive path

Tags: github, markdown, wiki

I would like to use the HTML `img` tag in a Github Wiki page.
It works with absolute path like

```
<img align="left" src="https://github.com/..../wiki/images/image.png" width="50%">
```

But doesn't work if I write

```
<img align="left" src="images/image.png" width="50%">
```

The image is in the "images" folder in the Wiki repository and the following syntax works.

```
[[images/image.png]]
```

I want to use the `<img>` tag in order to have the possibility to use attributes like `align="left"` or `width="50%"`.

And I would like to use realtive path in order to work offline and to sync the repo only at the end of the editing.

Note that I'm talking about the wiki page not a normal readme. I know that in a readme the `img` tag works also with realtive paths.

Comment: Where is the image hosted? Is it in the repository? Or are you using a wiki repository?

Comment: To use the relative path in the wiki, the image should be in te wiki repository. So i hve put the image in the "images" folder in the wiki repository but the img tag now doesn't work. Only [[images/image.png]] works.

Answer (score 1):

GitHub wikis turns relative links to absolute links only when using the `[[…]]` syntax only. You will therefore need to use absolute links only, host the images elsewhere… or ask GitHub to fix it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Since in the Readme you can use the img tag with a relative path to the repository, I thought you could do the same on the wiki too.